# how to set selected value from ul li based drop down to SELECTED

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to set the selected value as selected just like in select box, but i cannot do it, following is my HTML, i have also attached the Fiddle with it so that i can show my CSS too,

```
<section class="main">
   <div class="wrapper-demo">
      <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-2" tabindex="1">
       select Color
       <ul class="dropd">
        <li style="border-right-color:#F6EB61" value="F6EB61">
         <a>100 C</a>
        </li>
        <li style="border-right-color:#F7EA48" value="F7EA48">
         <a>101 C</a>
        </li>
        <li style="border-right-color:#FCE300" value="FCE300">
         <a>102 C</a>
        </li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

This is my Java script code

```
$(document).ready(function (e)
    {
        function DropDown(el) {
            this.dd = el;
            this.initEvents();
        }
        DropDown.prototype = {
            initEvents: function () {
                var obj = this;

                obj.dd.on('click', function (event) {
                    $(this).toggleClass('active');
                    event.stopPropagation();
                });
            }
        }
        var dd = new DropDown($('#dd'));
        $(document).click(function () {
            // all dropdowns
            $('.wrapper-dropdown-2').removeClass('active');
        });
});
```

**Demo FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/h65gbpu0/4/

Comment: Your `<ul>` tag is not closed before second `</div>` in your fiddle demo, like

 ` </li></ul></div></div></section>`

Comment: @VPK:Thanks i corrected it check the updated link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/h65gbpu0/6/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dropd li').on('click', function() {
        console.log('clicked');
        var val = $(this).find('a').html();
        var col = '#' + $(this).attr('value');
        console.log(col);
        $('.selected').css('border-right', '20px solid' + col);
        $('.selected').html(val);
    });
});

<div class="selected" style="margin-right:30px;"> select Color</div>
```

Comment: The demo is actually what i want but its strange that i am getting `var col = '#' + $(this).attr('value');` as `#0`, any suggestion why value is becoming zero? Although its not zero on Fiddle but i have it on my end, i will try to change js library in mean time i.e try older. May be that is what is causing trouble.

Comment: Yes got the problem jQuery 1.8.3 is giving this problem, i guess lower will also give same problem.

Comment: yea, the lowest jQuery version you should use moving forward is 1.11